# Golang matches characters to get substrings

Tags: regex, go

`https://<some strings>appid=c5f1b8ee7da1&source=<some strings>&path=<some strings>`

I want to match `appid=` and `&` to get `c5f1b8ee7da1`

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#Parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `net/url` package to parse the URL.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    s := "https://example.com?appid=c5f1b8ee7da1&source=asd&path=123"
    u, err := url.Parse(s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    params, err := url.ParseQuery(u.RawQuery)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(params.Get("appid"))
}
```

Go Play: https://goplay.space/#JTEq0wAlW1U